# Bootstrap 4 - Mobile site is too wide. Side-scrolling occurs. Probable syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website which has multiple backgrounds ontop of eachother using Sass and Bootstrap. My issue is, in the mobiles view of the site, you can scroll left or right and I don't want that. Also, the navbar is really messed up - the toggle button makes it go far too high.
Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4z5ty868/

I think the problem is somewhere in or around the navbar, or maybe an incorrect number of `<div>`s?
Basically, I'm super confused!
Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `btn` class. You've included `white-space: nowrap;` there, causing the buttons not to yield to the screen edges. Remove that line or overwrite with `white-space: normal;` and your horizontal scrolling issue is resolved.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]